# curl get request in php

Tags: php, curl, get

I am building a GET request to send of variables, It works without the variables but not with.

Have I built it wrong ?

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://ws.mysite.com/outside.svc/AssessmentActivityInsert?/&userID=' . $userID . '&score=' . $percentile .'&assessmentID= '. $testID . ' &assessmentTitle= '. $testName .'\',',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'sent from mysite'
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your url to:

```
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://ws.mysite.com/outside.svc/AssessmentActivityInsert/?userID=' . $userID . '&score=' . $percentile .'&assessmentID= '. $testID . '&assessmentTitle= '. $testName,
```

- Your `?` is in the wrong place
- You don't need `&` in the first parameter
- `&assessmentTitle= '. $testName .'\',',` is wrong. It should be just `&assessmentTitle= '. $testName,`
- And your `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` is invalid.

Comment: how should the CURLOPT_USERAGENT be ?

Comment: could i get away without the user agent

Comment: @BenjaminOats take a look at http://thisinterestsme.com/php-set-curl-user-agent/. Most of the time you don't need to send it, unless the server requires (ie. ensure you are using a browser, etc.)

Comment: still cant get it to GET but ill keep trying